# Android service does not work independently

Tags: android, android-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Service makes Activity not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338888/android-service-makes-activity-not-responding)

I use service to synchronize data between database and view. But the service does not work properly, whenever I use service to work long task, the view stop response (I can't do any event in UI) and I have to wait the service has done. Here is my service:

```
public class SyncService extends Service{
private static final String TAG = "SyncService";
@Override
public void onCreate()
{       
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "call onBind");
    return new DataManagerBinder();
}

private class DataManagerBinder extends Binder implements IUserDataManager
{
    @Override
    public void doProcess(Activity mView)
    {
        //do some long task (not touch UI thread)
        // this will cause the view not response
        syncDB();
        // update view after process completed
        mView.updateViewOnComplete();
    }

}
```

I try to bind this service in client activity

```
//the interface to handle binder 
IUserDataManager  viewManager = null;    
ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
{

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "connection closed unexpectedly");
        viewManager = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "serviceConnection onServiceConnected");
        viewManager = (IUserDataManager) binder;
        viewManager.doProcess(MyActivity.this);
    }
};

    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, SyncService.class);
    bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Please give me the solution for that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While others have given some responses, I don't know if the main point has been emphasized:
  While a `Service` sounds like something that would automatically run in the background, it does *not*.  It's merely a piece of code that can react to intents without maintaining a UI.  However, the UI thread still does the processing for the Service.

By contrast, it looks like what you want, is a `Service` that *sits* in the background and does some work in a background thread.  You will *use* the Service class to spawn a new thread, this is typically done on response to some intent, which you can define (usually in your `onStart()` or something similar).  You will probably start a new thread which actually does the work updating the database, etc..., and use your main Service to coordinate to that thread.

As it looks like you *also* want to communicate with the service, you will have to implement an appropriate `Messenger` and `Handler` pair to keep track of messages you pass between the UI and the Service (coordinating a background thread), and also (possibly) some way (also perhaps a messenger) of coordinating between the Service and the background thread.

As others have noted, you can also use `AsyncTask` to do things on the UI thread and use a background thread "seamlessly."

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) regarding services, specifically the "What is a Service?" paragraph. The service runs on the main UI thread. Take a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), should solve your issue. The work here is done in a background thread, and the results are sent back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Android closes service after sometime to save resources.
However you can prevent this from happening using something like

```
int onStartCommand(Intent, int, int){
return START_STICKY;
}
```

ref [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: I tried it but not work. I think this is not my problem. The service cause the view 'pause' when do long task.